# How to add button in email template

Tags: email, templates, button, odoo

I want to add a button in email template and want to call a method based on that button click.

can anyone suggest me how can i do this?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In html email, you are limited to html and css, so the only button you can create is a hyperlink. You could however pass some url parameters to a web page that does all your dirty work for you.

The design options are:

- An image wrapped in a href `<a href=""><img src=""></a>`
- Full CSS button - by building it in CSS so that it shows with images turned off.
- "Bulletproof Buttons" - using a combination of CSS and background images. They fallback to the css if the images are turned off. See [buttons.cm](http://buttons.cm/) for a great example